# Using .load with an element's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery 2.0.3, I'm having issues trying to do something like so:

`$("[data-load]").load($(this).attr("data-load"));"`

And the associated HTML looks like: `<div data-load="markup/fonts.html"></div>`

I can retrieve the correct value from the attribute but I can't get it to load anything. What's more, if I try `$("[data-load]").load($(this).attr("data-load").toString());` I get an `Error: Unable to get value of the property 'toString': object is null or undefined`

Any clues?

**Edit:** Sorry, syntax was correct. Just wrong when typing it here.

**Resolution**: Jeez, I'm a bonehead. What I was looking for what this:

```
$("[data-load]").each(function (index) {
    $(this).load($(this).attr("data-load"));
});
```

Comment: You are missing a quote in the first part: `$("[data-load])`

Answer (score 1):

why `$("[data-load])` - you forgot one more `"`?

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution**: Jeez, I'm a bonehead. What I was looking for what this:

```
$("[data-load]").each(function (index) {
    $(this).load($(this).attr("data-load"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all elements that have a `data-load` attribute, regardless of its value, you have the correct selector:

```
$("[data-load]")
```

However, the problem is when you're calling the `.load()` function; you need a way to refer to a specific element. I'd suggest using `.each()`:

```
$('[data-load]').each(function() {
    $(this).load($(this).attr('data-load'));
});
```

That iterates through each of the elements that matched the selector, individually calling `.load()` on them and passing the `data-load` attributes value *for that specific element* to it.